# binding the seleted text to a property of selectbox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I create a small application to add text from textarea to div block..I want when user click on yellow div text not get append and the properties (font family, font size) of the selected text also highlight in the selectbox

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#page1').click(function(e){
var $el = $("<li class='text'>"+$('#ta').val()+"</li>"),
    $this = $(this), offset = $this.offset();
$el.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: e.pageX - offset.left,
    top: e.pageY - offset.top
});
$this.append($el);
($el).draggable();
$("#page1 li").click(function(){
$("#page1 li").removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass("active");

});
});
    $("#fs").change(function() {
        $('li.active').css("font-family", $(this).val());
    });
    $("#size").change(function() {
        $('li.active').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
    });

  });
```

Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sharma_pooja/P2Kyk/31/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation is not very clear as to exactly what you want. I think you want something like this:

```
$('#page1').click(function(e){
  if( $(e.target).is('li.text') ){
      return;
  }
  /* other code*/

})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/P2Kyk/32/

Comment: thnks! @charlie for the answer can u also help me for updating the selected property in selectbox (for ex. as user select comicsans for one active text and arial for other so on click of first.. selectbox change it to comicsans and on click of other text...selectbox change to arial)

Comment: use change handler of select to modify css based on select value

Comment: looked at fiddle again...you already have code that works.... but only if item is `active`

Comment: change handler is working fine ..i want onclick of selected text change selectbox option

Comment: OK.. I wasn't understanding issue...try this  http://jsfiddle.net/P2Kyk/33/  I added a few comments that should help understand what's happening

Comment: solution only works when clicking on li. WIll need to change reset value of select when you add new text to green area also